# Python Random's with no repeats

Tags: python, list, random

Here is my code, im trying to fill a list with 7 numbers between 0-6 with no duplicates, and a random order every time.  Here is my code but I keep getting an error "list assignment index out of range", I don't see where my error is though.  Here is my code:

```
    import random
def generate():
    listA = []
    for x in range(0,6):
        listA[x] = random.sample(range(6), 1)
generate()
print(listA)
```

Comment: hint: when you have a list of length 0, doing `my_list[whatever] = something` will always fail. The list will not resize itself to accommodate new elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It'd be more effective to just `shuffle` the result of `range`.

```
>>> from random import shuffle
>>>
>>> r = range(7)
>>> shuffle(r)
>>> r
[5, 3, 6, 4, 1, 0, 2]
```

Note that in Python 3 you have to explicitly convert `r` to a list:

```
>>> r = list(range(7))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [random.shuffle](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.shuffle).

```
list_ = list(range(7)) #a list from 0 to 6. list() not needed in Python 2
shuffle(list_)
print(list_)
```

However, if your shuffled list is big, you should consider:

> Note that for even rather small len(x), the total number of permutations of x is larger than the period of most random number generators; this implies that most permutations of a long sequence can never be generated.

And so you should manually implement it:

```
yourlist = range(1000) #or a bigger number, or an arbitrary list
yournewlist = []
for i in range(len(yourlist)):
    yournewlist.append(yourlist.pop(random.randint(0, len(yourlist)-1)))
```

Notice I calculate `len(yourlist)` N+1 times. This value should be never stored in a variable. The first calculation defines the iteration (in Python 2, you could use `xrange` instead of `range` for the count iteration). The following iterations will have a different value of `len(yourlist)` (from N to 1). Remember that `randint(lowerBound, uppweBound)` will include upperBound, so you should ALWAYS use 0 and the length - 1 to get a valid list index. This constrasts to many other languages like Pascal which do not include the upperBound value among the expected results for integer random functions.

Remember: both the algorithm I described AND the use os shuffle alter the original list. My alg. puts the result in a distinct list.

Answer (score 0):

To assign an element past the end of a list, use `listA.append(…)`.

What you're trying to do is replace the value for a slot that doesn't exist, which is why you get an `IndexError`.

Also, I'm pretty sure you just wanted `listA = random.sample(range(6), 6)`. What you've written just does 6 separate 1-element samplings, with no repeats *in each sampling*.

(Alternatively, you could just write `listA = range(6)` then `random.shuffle(listA)`.)